# How do i fix illegal characters error when using text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to load a text file into a listbox and keep getting an error saying "illegal characters in path" this is my code

```
                String path = Resources.Animals;
                listBox1.DataSource = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

The text file is just a list of animal names in this format

```
Canidae
Felidae
Cat
Cattle
Dog
Donkey
```

each word has its own line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Resources.Animals` is already returning the resource's content, not the path to it. So simply having `listBox1.DataSource = Resources.Animals.Split('\n');` should be sufficient.

Comment: Now i get an error saying "Complex databinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource"

Comment: Yep that makes sense, you cannot assign a String to a List. How does the `Animals` resource looks like, can you post the first few lines?

Comment: I posted it, it looks like a sentence but each word has its own line

Comment: This worked it all being on the same line made the error